# HTML helper doesn't output appropriate link based on parameters

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

For some reason, I cannot get HTML helper to output `/users/workspace`

I'm currently testing the following code on `/users/login`

```
echo '<li>'.$this->Html->link(h($this->request->getParam('controller')),['controller' => $this->request->getParam('controller'), 'action' => 'workspace']).'</li>';
echo '<li>'.$this->Html->link(h($this->request->getParam('controller')),['controller' => $this->request->getParam('controller'), 'action' => 'anything-here-works']).'</li>';
```

Will output:

```
<li><a href="/slat">Users</a></li>
<li><a href="/slat/users/anything-here-works">Users</a></li>
```

Is `workspace` a reserved word or something? What am I missing or not understanding?

I'm on CakePHP 3.10.

Noting a route setup:

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'workspace']);
```

Comment: Your route setup has said that the `workspace` action of the `Users` controller is to be available at `/`. Assuming that `/slat` is your app prefix. So, this is precisely what it is supposed to be outputting in this case.

Comment: Would the solution, in this case, to specify the URL when calling the HTML helper? (ie. /users/workspace?) Seems to work.

Comment: When "/" works to get you that page, why would you want to use "/users/workspace"?

Comment: by default, I have the root be users/workspace, which expects some credentials, then forwards to /users/login. For non-admin users, they can't see users/index, thus I need to have the link up top, which is actually breadcrumbs, be users/workspace.

Comment: There's something stopping you from having breadcrumbs that use "users/workspace" as the text of the link, but "/" as the URL?

Comment: I'm revisiting this entire idea of mine. Essentially, specific users need to see users/xyz instead of index in the breadcrumbs. I've come up with something. Lastly, if you want to put up your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'workspace']);
```

As i understood, the base path routing is already defined in the route as above, so it generates "`<li><a href="/slat">Users</a></li>"`, when the link created for

"$this->Html->link(h($this->request->getParam('controller')),['controller' => $this->request->getParam('controller'), 'action' => 'workspace'])"

> > here controller = "Users" and action="workspace", hence it gets the base path "/slat" as matches with "/" on the route.

i think "slat" is your project directory on localhost.

You can generate links in more customized way, ie:-

```
<a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller'=>'Users','action'=>'workspace']);">" >Link</a>
```

And if you need routing for specific users type ( like admin ), you can create prefix routing [prefix routing on cakephp 3.x](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

also, $this->request->getParam('controller') gives the current controller name, so the link might become wrong when you jump to other pages.

you can mention the controller name directly instead of using "getParam"

also for generating link for current controller's action ( which is mentioned on the template file of the current controller only ), you do not need to mention the controller's name, only action name and parameters are sufficient.

ie:

```
<a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['action'=>'workspace']);">" >Link</a>
```